# Abort after redirect in Express JS

Tags: javascript, redirect, express

I would like abort request after I send a redirect in Express JS.
Now, when I try to redirect, the following sentences are executed.

Comment: Where's the code?

Comment: `return` after sending the redirect.

Comment: But there are async callbacks in execution